# Keras custom layer: How to multiply the input of the layer with the defined argument of the custom layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom layer in Keras where it takes the input and multiply it with a tensor that is passed to the layer as an argument. I also do various operations such as fft and ifft's (and their respective shifts) which are irrelevant for this question I presume, as I have tested their correctness, so I need to define a custom layer.

I have tried debugging my code line by line and it seemed to work, yet the layer does not give the expected results when I test it in a model. I also tried to get the shapes of variables and tried to tweak by squeezing the argument, yet to no avail.

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1), name='inputs')
inputs2 = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1), name='k_space_real')
inputs3 = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1), name='k_space_imag')

concat1 = concatenate([inputs2, inputs3], axis=3)

concat2 = concatenate([inputs1, concat1], axis=3)

outputs = CustomLayer(arg)(concat2)

self.model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2, inputs3], outputs=[outputs])
#################################   
class CustomLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mask, **kwargs):
        super(UpdatedDCLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mask = mask

    def call(self, inputs):
        a = inputs[:, :, :, 0] 
        input_k_space_real = inputs[:, :, :, 1] 
        input_k_space_imag = inputs[:, :, :, 2] 
        input_k_space = tf.complex(input_k_space_real, input_k_space_imag) 
        input_k_space = tf.cast(input_k_space, dtype=tf.complex128)

        mask_bool = tf.cast(self.mask, dtype=tf.bool) 
        inv_mask = tf.cast(tf.math.logical_not(mask_bool), dtype=tf.complex128) 

        intermediary = tf.cast(a, dtype=tf.complex128)
        intermediary_k_space = tf.spectral.fft2d(intermediary)
        intermediary_k_space = tf.roll(intermediary_k_space, shift=[128, 128], axis=[0, 1]) 

        output_intermediary = tf.math.multiply(intermediary_k_space, tf.squeeze(inv_mask))
        input_dc_k_space = tf.math.add(output_intermediary, input_k_space)
        input_dc_k_space = tf.roll(input_dc_k_space, shift=[-128, -128], axis=[0, 1])
        output_dc = tf.spectral.ifft2d(input_dc_k_space)
        output_intermediary = tf.roll(output_intermediary, shift=[-128, -128], axis=[0, 1]) 
        output_intermediary = tf.spectral.ifft2d(output_intermediary)
        output_dc = tf.expand_dims(output_dc, -1) 
        output_intermediary = tf.expand_dims(output_intermediary, -1) 
        return [tf.cast(tf.math.abs(output_dc), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.cast(tf.math.abs(output_intermediary), dtype=tf.float32)]



    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        shape = list(input_shape)
        shape[-1] = 1
        return [tuple(shape), tuple(shape)]
```

This layer will be used multiple times during the model and input1 is dependent on previous CNN's, where input2 and 3 are constants. All inputs have the same shape [sample_size, 256, 256, 1].

This custom layer gives a result, but not the expected one. The problem seems to stem from this line:

```
output_intermediary = tf.math.multiply(intermediary_k_space, tf.squeeze(inv_mask))
```

thus my question, as stated above, is about this multiplication process. I may have asked this badly, if so, my apologies.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Sounds you don't need a custom layer at all. "Multiplying with a tensor" is what you do in the most basic fully-connected layer. If you mean "multiply with an ordinary tensor, then multiply the outcome with another tensor" then you could just multiply those two tensors up front. Alternatively, insert an extra fully-connected layer with linear activation function.

Comment: The thing is, i cropped the irrelevant parts where I take the fft and ifft's of the inputs, so I need a custom layer to do those as well. I should have stated that in the question, sorry.

Comment: To be honest, that doesn't seem like you need a custom Keras layer either, just pre-processing of your data before you hand it to Keras.

Comment: This layer is going to be used multiple times and the input1 in custom layer is the output of the previous CNN consisting of five layers. input2 and input3 are k-space parts (real and imaginary) of the original input, so they have the same sample size, so they are relevant to input1. This custom layer iteratively returns the reconstruction image for more than one times in my model. I thought it was better to remove and edit my code for clarity, I think I should edit the code and change it with the original one, maybe I surely do not need a custom layer.

Comment: What is `arg` in your code?

Comment: a tensor of size (256, 256, 1), defined outside and passed as the argument.